Every Forbidden thing has a corresponding opposite
what is the source that every forbidden thing has a corresponding opposite good in the Torah?
For example, I heard correct me if I'm wrong there is a certain kosher fish that tastes like bacon although it's kosher called Shibota and the sages recommend eating that instead of the bad.
Also How to find the corresponding opposite good for everything bad(Like is there source for a list of them)?

See Chullin 109b

The Talmud says:

Yalta said to her husband Rav Naḥman: Now as a rule, for any item that the Merciful One prohibited to us, He permitted to us a similar item. [Chullin 109b]

Numerous examples follow.
